# if i migrate locally, can i execute the same migration on the server?

Tags: laravel, migration

Before I execute a migration on localhost I want to be sure that I can still execute the same migration on my server.

Will i still be able to execute the same migration remotely or will laravel mark that migration as done somewhere?

Comment: I am using version control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration information is stored inside the database that was migrated (in a "migrations" table). As long as your localhost and your server are not looking at the same database, you'll be fine.